# May I set multiple names in /etc/hostname?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, hostname

My server is meant to have one name in the datacenter ISP's domain and another in our company domain. How do I set this up correctly? Can I set multiple names in /etc/hostname? (The OS is Ubuntu 10.04 Serer).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A server can only have one hostname listed in `/etc/hostname`. I would list your company's preferred name there. You can, however, point as many different DNS records at the server as you want, either via your `/etc/hosts` or via your company's DNS server infrastructure.